# Reduce bin size for Matlab rainflow counting

Tags: matlab, count, histogram, bin

I performed a rainflow count using:

```
[c,hist,edges,rmm,idx] = rainflow(Z,t);
TT = array2table(c,'VariableNames',{'Count','Range','Mean','Start','End'})
histogram('BinEdges',edges','BinCounts',sum(hist,2))
```

It seems to work but the bins are very thick, meaning the results are not very clear. I see that this is because of the bin edges but when I change these, it just changes the edges without also changing the bins. Does someone knows how I can change the bin sizes (so the number of bins) with a rainflow count? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please [edit] the question to contain an image, because the [`histogram` documentation](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.histogram.html) suggests that changing the edges and amount of bins is done in this way. I think, judging your description, that you don't want to move the bin edges, but rather want to increase the number of bins itself, thus making them smaller.

Comment: Sorry I indeed tried to say that. Smaller bin sizes. However I don't manage to change the number of bins while the number of cycles stay intact. In other words: I can not change the bincounts.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by making a duplicate Rainflow function named Rainflow2.

In the Rainflow function, I simply modified lines 287 and 288 to include the nbins variable

`[~,xedges,binx] = histcounts(xc,10);`

`[~,yedges,biny] = histcounts(xm,10);`

In this case, I wanted 10 bins for both the x and y-axis.
you can also specify the bin edges, see [more options here](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histcounts.html)

Don't forget to call your new rainflow2 function in your main script.